Как в EmEditor произвести поиск сразу нескольких запросов
Возможно ли в EmEditor через регулярные выражения делать поиск сразу по нескольким запросам (к примеру, мне надо найти "вт/, .вт, и вт."), чтобы не по одному искать, а сразу все 3 вышеуказанных в примере варианта?

Просто перечислите в строке поиска все требуемые варианты следующим образом:
(вт\/|\.вт|вт\.)

